# How to validate inclusion of array content in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, validation

Hi I have an array column in my model:

```
t.text :sphare, array: true, default: []
```

And I want to validate that it includes only the elements from the list ("Good", "Bad", "Neutral")

My first try was:

```
 validates_inclusion_of :sphare, in: [ ["Good"], ["Bad"], ["Neutral"] ]
```

But when I wanted to create objects with more then one value in sphare ex(["Good", "Bad"] the validator cut it to just ["Good"].

My question is:

How to write a validation that will check only the values of the passed array, without comparing it to fix examples?

Edit added part of my FactoryGirl and test that failds:

Part of my FactoryGirl:

```
sphare ["Good", "Bad"]
```

and my rspec test:

```
  it "is not valid with wrong sphare" do
    expect(build(:skill, sphare: ["Alibaba"])).to_not be_valid
  end
 it "is valid with proper sphare" do
    proper_sphare = ["Good", "Bad", "Neutral"]
    expect(build(:skill, sphare: [proper_sphare.sample])).to be_valid
  end
```

Comment: Try `validates_inclusion_of :sphare, in: [ "Good", "Bad", "Neutral" ]`

Comment: @Pavan - It doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
validates :sphare, inclusion: { in: ["Good", "Bad", "Neutral"] }
```

or, you can be fancy by using the short form of creating the array of strings: `%w(Good Bad Neutral)`:

```
validates :sphare, inclusion: { in: %w(Good Bad Neutral) }
```

See the [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) for more usage and example of `inclusion`.

#### Update

As the Rails built-in validator does not fit your requirement, you can add a custom validator in your model like following:

```
validate :correct_sphare_types

private

def correct_sphare_types
  if self.sphare.blank?
    errors.add(:sphare, "sphare is blank/invalid")
  elsif self.sphare.detect { |s| !(%w(Good Bad Neutral).include? s) }
    errors.add(:sphare, "sphare is invalid")
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn`t work I got error sphare is not part of the list :(

Comment: How about: `validates_inclusion_of :sphare, in: %w( Good Bad Neutral)`?

Comment: I think the problem is that it compers values without nesting them in array, so it looks for "Good" where it should look for ["Good"]

Comment: okay, in that case you can use a custom validator. I will update my answer soon with the custom validator code.

Comment: Please try my updated code with custom validation. It assumes that, your sphare array can have only `Good Bad Neutral`, if it has anything outside these 3 values, then it will be an invalid sphare and will not be saved. Let me know if this assumption is correct or not.

Comment: it pass proper "valid", and" valid with proper value" tests, so it works, but it fails with "blank sphare test" (no method fo nilclass), and "wrong value test" (undefined method t)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91346/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-kazik).

Answer (score 6):

You can implement your own `ArrayInclusionValidator`:

```
# app/validators/array_inclusion_validator.rb
class ArrayInclusionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # your code here

    record.errors.add(attribute, "#{attribute_name} is not included in the list")
  end
end
```

In the model it looks like this:

```
# app/models/model.rb
class YourModel < ApplicationRecord
  ALLOWED_TYPES = %w[one two three]
  validates :type_of_anything, array_inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_TYPES }
end
```

Examples can be found here:

- https://github.com/sciencehistory/kithe/blob/master/app/validators/array_inclusion_validator.rb
- https://gist.github.com/bbugh/fadf8c65b7f4d3eaa55e64acfc563ab2